# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable, trying to solve subscriptable error but not able to solve it

Tags: python

I am trying implement a simple logic but I am not getting why I am getting subcriptable error

Comment: What is `weightVector[counter]` supposed to be doing? The error seems to be here.

Comment: `weights[k][i][j]` will also not work without defining a suitable data structur.

Comment: Try printing the `type(weightVector)` and also its value.

Comment: I have updated the original function

Comment: @RichaBhuwania that's a list

Comment: @RichaBhuwania It a list of elements of weightvector containing 17 one's

Comment: What is the value of `_layerSizes`?

Comment: @RichaBhuwania 10 inputs

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get `[counter]` from `weightVector` but weightVector is declared as an integer 5 at the top.

Answer (score 0):

The error persists in `weightVector`. It is defined as `number` and you are trying to access it as a `list`. It can be resolved by either converting `weightVector` to list or not accessing `weightVector[counter]`.

One quick solution would be:

```
counter = 0
weightVector = 5
weights = []
for k  in range(4-1):
  print("k  is ",k)
  for i  in range(k):
    print("i is ", i)
    for j in range(k + 1):
      print("j is ", j)
      weights[k][i][j]= weightVector #using only weightVector instead if its counter
      counter +=1
```

Another solution: Converting `weightVector` as `list`.

```
counter = 0
weightVector = [1,2,3,4,5] # Converting it to list and adding certain values.
weights = []
for k  in range(4-1):
  print("k  is ",k)
  for i  in range(k):
    print("i is ", i)
    for j in range(k + 1):
      print("j is ", j)
      weights[k][i][j]= weightVector #using only weightVector instead if its counter
      counter +=1
```